# How do you get only visible items in a credit memo

Tags: creditmemo

I'm trying to get the products from a credit memo but they are duplicated if configurable, so instead of 3 products I get 6, configurable and the associated simple one.

```
$creditmemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $key => $item) {

//gets products configurable and simple ones

}


var_dump($item->getData())
```

shows it as an array with 6 products, the only difference is that the simple ones don't have a price associated.

How do I get only simple ones or only configurable ones with the superattribute option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One can use the following condition to get only visible items in creditmemo collection.

```
foreach ($creditMemo->getAllItems() as $item) {
    if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) continue;
    echo $item->getSku();
}
```

Using above code, you will have only visible items in creditmemo.

Answer (score 0):

try to use is this function:

```
getAllVisibleItems()
```

I use it on the quote, order and invoice, I never used agains a creditmemo object but I think it will work.

Comment: unfortunately `$creditmemo->getAllVisibleItems()` does not return anything

Comment: In this case you can go back to the getAllItem and check both $_item->getProductType() then if  you have to go deeper and look inside the item->buyRequest

Comment: Not able to find the function `getAllVisibleItems ` In credit memo